# Unable to catch and input some dynamically generated number in an inputbox to populate some result

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, request, python-requests

Hello I am trying to scrape information from a website https://www.nsekra.com/. We need to select `Non-Individual` from dropdown then enter the PAN as `AAAHA0064Q`, and the `captcha number` which generates a random number every time the website is visited or opened. After that we need to press `Search` button so that the required information can be fetched.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get('https://www.nsekra.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'lxml')
dictinfo = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}

# trying to enter PAN as 'AAAHA0064Q'
dictinfo['txtPan']='AAAHA0064Q'

# trying to get captcha number & passing to textbox
captcha_number = soup.select_one("#lblDynamicCode").text
print('Fetched Catpcha No. -> ',captcha_number);
dictinfo['txtImageBox'] = captcha_number

# passsing pan no. & captcha number to the request method  
resp2 = requests.post('https://www.nsekra.com/',data=dictinfo)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(resp2.text,'lxml')
name = soup2.select_one('#lblKra_name').text
print('KRA Name : '+name)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
print('Fetched Catpcha No. -> ',s);
```

> Fetched Catpcha No. -> 757205

```
print(soup2.prettify());
```

> [image]

```
print('KRA Name : '+name)
```

> KRA Name : &nbsp

**Expected Output**

> KRA Name : CVL KRA

As you can see I able to get the captcha number, but when I'm trying to passed it to the website, it regenerating new number everytime when the website is visited. So basically, the above code does fetch the captcha number but while visting to the website, new number is generated & instead of new number, the old or previous number is passed, & not the current one at when the website is visited. How can I grab and make use of that dynamically generated number in order to fetch the results I'm interested in?***I like to stick to the `requests` library to get it done.***

Comment: I would suggest using ```selenium```, instead of BeatifulSoup, you can easily interact with the page.

Comment: It can be done just with `request`, see my answer.

Comment: @MITHU - Thank you much MITHU.

Comment: No problem @David. The question seemed to be interesting to me as well and that is the reason I decided to put that bounty. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part is doing your requests in session and not posting all parameters found in input as data (only `btnAllKRA` is important):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as session:     # <---- IMPORTANT!

    resp = session.get('https://www.nsekra.com/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'lxml')
    dictinfo = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}

    # trying to enter PAN as 'AAAHA0064Q'
    dictinfo['txtPan']='AAAHA0064Q'

    # trying to get captcha number & passing to textbox
    captcha_number = soup.select_one("#lblDynamicCode").text
    print('Fetched Catpcha No. -> ',captcha_number);
    dictinfo['txtImageBox'] = captcha_number

    for k in [*dictinfo.keys()]:        # <---- IMPORTANT!
        if k.lower().startswith('btn') and k.lower() != 'btnallkra':
            del dictinfo[k]

    # passsing pan no. & captcha number to the request method
    resp2 = session.post('https://www.nsekra.com/',data=dictinfo)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(resp2.text,'lxml')

    name = soup2.select_one('#lblKra_name').text
    print('KRA Name : '+name)
```

Prints:

```
Fetched Catpcha No. ->  314885
KRA Name : CVL KRA
```

Comment: So perfect!!! The system can't let me award this bounty right away. I have to wait 12 hours. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU Glad to help. Lets wait then :)

Comment: @AndrejKesely - Thank you so much Andrej. I didn't hope it could be done with request library. Can you please explain me (_second important part in code_) `del dictinfo[k]`, how BtnPrint, btnkra, btnCancel is affecting the result. Because since you are using SESSION, it should give ouptut in that session itself so how deleting keys of above three affecting the output.

Comment: @David I had scraped these types of sites before, I think on the server they are running ASP.NET. My understanding is, that the server needs to know which button has been pressed (that means which `btn` is in the request) and according that the server will do internal routing.

Comment: @AndrejKesely - Ok thank you so much Andrej, so I guess earlier all the buttons were passed in the request.

Comment: @David Yes, exactly. That's why I delete the unused buttons from the dict.

Answer (score 2):

Although you have clearly mentioned that you wanna go for `requests` module to grab that name, I like to provide you with a selenium related solution anyway just in case anybody with similar problem comes across this post to seek any sort of solution.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.nsekra.com/"

def get_name(driver,url):

    driver.get(url)
    select = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[id='ddlKyc']"))))
    select.select_by_visible_text("Non-Individual")

    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"txtPan"))).send_keys("AAAHA0064Q")
    dynamic_number = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"lblDynamicCode"))).text
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"txtImageBox"))).send_keys(dynamic_number)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnAllKRA"))).click()

    name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "lblKra_name"))).text
    print(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    try:
        get_name(driver,link)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
CVL KRA
```

Answer (score 0):

The response to first GET request includes some cookies which look like security tokens..

So, assuming you are using the site according to your license agreements when using python, you can include the same cookies in the 2nd request, e.g. using a [Session](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects):

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    resp = session.get(...)
    ...
    resp2 = session.post(...)
```

Comment: Before modifying the question for bounty I went that route by creating a session and reused them later like you suggeted but that didn't help me fetch the required results.